# Is it possible to optimize this regular expression?

Tags: optimization, expression, reduce

I have this regular expression :

```
^4\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?(?:[0-9]\s?[0-9]\s?[0-9])?$
```

I had my credit card number, and I want to allow space in the string that the user will enter. I want this : 
4912 1234 1234 1234
4912123412341234

Is it possible to reduce my regular expression to had less \s? and [0-9]?
Tancks

Comment: [0-9] is pretty much the same as \d so you may want to use that to make it less in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use curly braces (`{}`) to specify "repeat a certain number of times"; for instance, `[0-9]{16}` means exactly 16 digits, and `(?:\s[0-9]){16}` means `\s[0-9]` repeated 16 times.

Comment: Thancks! This help me a lot! ;)